# How can I see if someone downloads files from a file directory on my website?

Tags: webserver, file-download, analysis

If someone browse the file directory of a folder on my website and download a few files.

1) Is there any way I can see that this has been done?

2) Is there any way I can see which files has been downloaded?

[image: Example of a website file directory]

Comment: In the server’s access log...?

Answer (score 2):

These are two *easiest* possibilities that I can think of

- create a Perl `cgi`, or `PHP` application that creates a linked list of the files in the directory. The links double as a logger that provides for example; `IP`, `browser`, and also increments a "count" of how many times the file has been downloaded. (I've done (created) this many times in the past, and it's simple to make)
- Create a script that searches the web log(s) for the file names of interest, and prints the lines containing them.